# How to securely pass data for backend update from client?

Tags: web-application, man-in-the-middle

Suppose I have 3 videos on my page. Client can watch each of the videos, once complete, he would earn `n`points depending on which video he has watched. I want to POST that `n` for the specific client to the backend to update his total points.

I'm researching on how to accomplish this securely as I don't have much security knowledge. What I'm trying to avoid is someone manually adjusting the value of `n` and having the backend incorrectly update it or  a variation of the man-in-middle attack.

Comment: You won't find a perfect solution as y can't trust the client. All you can do is make it harder to fake. Thus shouldn't be a big problem as you really can't ever know if the user is "watching" the video

Comment: I'm not sure what MitM has to do with this? Are you concerned that a third party could modify the value of `n`? In that case, just use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in a completely secure way, since *you can not trust the client*. The server can never know if the user actually watched the video or not. I would advice against trying to obfuscate your code or making this to complicated - in the end a determined user will always be able to cheat anyway, and you are just making a mess of your code for no benefit. After all, the user might not even be in front of the computer while the video plays!

That said, you can make it harder to cheat. Here are some suggestions:

- Don't send `n`. Instead send a code unique to the video watched. While the user could simply change that code, at least she would not be able to set it to a ridiculously large number and gain billions of points.
- On the server, save the time that the user requests the page with a video. When the server recieves the "video watched" message, check that the time passed is not shorter than the length of the video. If so, you have found a cheater.
- If you stream the video, check that all of the video was actually downloaded before awarding points. Again, this is a check you need to do on the server.
- Finally, if this is for some kind of educational purpose, have a simple quizz at the end where the user is required to demonstrate a basic understanding of the concepts discuessed in the video.

Comment: This is very helpful start. Using the above points, how would you defend against a script that just runs and makes a request to my service posing as the client sending a video-id and a "video watched" signal after x-seconds, where x is the video length.

Comment: @user814628 You can't defend against that. If someone really wants to cheat, they will be able to. You do not control the client, therefore you can not know what happends there. Just as you can not know if the human user is even in the room when the video is played, you can not know if the computer actually played the video.

Comment: I understand that. I don't care if human is actually watching, don't want to validate that. Just want to be secure enough for amateur or intermediate hacker not to be able to get in.  So trying to think of any scenarios as possible. It might not be needed, but want to do my best. Anyways, I appreciate your help here.